# How could David lie with Bat Sheva if she had a Safek Get?

Tags: king-david, divorce, conditional-stipulation, arayot

Tosafos version of Rashi in the Gemara Kesubos 9b implies that there was a get on condition that Uria (Bat shevas husband) won't come back. So if David didn't know if Uria would come back or not how could he live with Bat sheva?

Or maybe that was David's mistake since the gemara said David Hamelech didn't sin. But this is David Hamelech we are talking about here!

Comment: R' Yosef Zevin, in Le'Or HaHalacha, has an extended discussion of War Gittin, and when they activated. And if they necessitated a remarriage on return.

Comment: −1. (1) No context. (Who are this "Uria" and this "Bet sheva"?) (2) What is this "Gemara 9b"? (3) I find it hard to believe that "in Tos [ = _Tosafos's_?] version of Rashi" there was an entire _get_. _Rashi_ tends to be brief and to the point, and a _get_ is customarily twelve lines (though, to be fair, I don't know that _Rashi_ held it was twelve lines). (4) Your second paragraph is *very* unclear. ¶ I know the answers to a lot of my questions here. I'm not saying the question's very unclear to me. I'm saying it's very unclear to the typical reader unfamiliar with _Bas Sheva_ and _g'mara_.

Comment: Your question is asked carefully and clearly. But it's worth pointing out for others that Tosefos themselves hold that the get was unconditional.

Answer (score 5):

Although the popularized understanding of the *Gemara* in *b.Shabbath 56a* is that *David haMelekh* never actually sinned with *Batsheva`* but only ***appeared*** to sin, the Gemara as a whole, and the tradition as taught by the *Rishonim* are not so monolithic on this question. In fact, aside from the statements made to this effect by *Rav Shemu'el Bar Nahmeni* and *Rebi Yehudhah haNasi* in this passage of *Masekheth Shabbath*, all other references made to the incident of *David* and *Uriyah haHiti* reflect the opposite view, namely that *David* did indeed commit the sin of *esheth ish*, and that such an interpretation is the obvious *peshuto shel miqra* (plain meaning of the Biblical text).

The dissonance with the popularly taught view begins with a line in the very text of the *Gemara* in *Shabbath 56* where *Rav* answers the objections to *David* sinning raised by both *Rebi* and *Rav Shemu'el bar Nahmeni* by saying, "Those who are descended from *David* seek to defend and expound his merits." In other words, he is noting that although the text of the *Tana"kh* clearly spells out the nature of *David*'s sin, due to the public and embarrassing mistakes of their esteemed forebear, they seek to expound the text in a forced way to exonerate him.

Other places in the *Gemara* which hold the opinion that *David haMelekh* did sin are:

- **b.Sanhedrin 107a** (*Batsheva* is a fully-married woman with whom *David* sinned)
- **b.Kethuboth 9a-b** (no names are explicitly mentioned, however the mefarshim and Rishonim understand the discussion to be making reference to *David* and *Batsheva*)
- **b.Avodah Zarah 4b-5a** (*David*, through his admission of guilt, elevates the "yoke of *teshuvah*)
- **Yoma 22b** (*David* is punished four-fold for sinning with *Batsheva*)

Amongst the *Rishonim* are also opinions to the contrary:

- The ***Riva"n*** (Shu"T Hakhmei Provanssia 71) relates that although *Haza"l* tried to be *limudh zekhuth* on *David*, the fact that he blatantly sinned with regard to *esheth ish* is the undeniable *peshuto shel miqra* from which the text can never budge.
- The ***Rada"q*** also affirms the sinning of *David* and *Batsheva*.
- ***Rav Yisshaq Abarbanel*** writes similarly to the *Riva"n* regarding the clear communication of the *Tana"kh* that *David* did indeed sin.

So, as specifically regards your question(s): The answer is that is that by having intercourse with *Batsheva*, the wife of *Uriya haHiti*, when the conditional get given by those going out to war in order to prevent *agunoth* only takes effect **after** a husband does not return from battle or dies, he committed *esheth ish*. It is for this reason that he did *teshuvah* and why *Nathan haNavi* assured him that he would not die for his sin (2 *Shemu'el* 12:13).

*Kol tuv*.

Comment: Fine, but it's still a question according to Rebbi

Comment: I should point out, that if she was a full aishes is she would have remained asur to both Uriah and Dovid. Since she later married Dovid and their son Shlomo was not a mamzer, then it appears that she could not have been an aishes ish at the time of the chet. Similarly the analogy used by the navi implies that she was not an aishes ish at the time of the sin.

Comment: @sabbahillel [that's not correct!](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.4.13).  Even if she remained forbidden to David, there would be no kareis involved and Shlomo wouldn't have been a mamzer.

Answer (score 1):

in the artscroll book Reb Mendel, Rabbi Mendel Kaplan zt'l is quoted as saying that David saw with divine inspiration (ruach hakodesh) that she was his soulmate in all the mystical worlds, just not yet in this one. there is support for this in that Solomon came specifically from her.

Comment: I'll tell that to the judge next time I got tried for rape.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that he did not know, and that was his sin.