# Did what David do to Batsheba and Uriah technically legal (not sin?)

Tags: sin, historical-figures, king-david

David is a king.

Uriah is fighting for him.

As a King David has right to send any of his soldiers to any missions. Presumably that includes suicidal mission.

It is possible that Batsheba is not even technically Uriah's wife. I've heard about something called retroactive divorce.

Let's presume that Batsheba is not technically Uriah's wife at that time. Is what David do technically a sin?

This is discussed here:
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/to-what-extent-is-psalm-514-poetic-exaggeration

> First, remember that David was king, and as king he answered to no one
>   but G-d. He could have ordered Uriah killed on whatever pretext and
>   then taken Bat-Sheva. He had that authority. Instead, what he did was
>   rely on the fact that Jewish soldiers going into battle are required
>   to give their wives conditional retroactive divorce papers which in
>   effect say: "I divorce you effective today if I do not return from war
>   by next month." Babyl. Talmud, Shab. 56a. As king, David could order
>   any of his soldiers on a suicide mission without apology. And because
>   of the retroactive divorce given to Bat-Sheva, David technically did
>   not commit adultery with her as she was divorced. But, as Nathan
>   pointed out, whether or not he was legally permitted to do all that he
>   did, G-d had warned him to be better than that. Accordingly, he owed
>   no apology to anyone (and could not apologize to the deceased Uriah)
>   but G-d.

Now what about if Batsheba is indeed Uriah's wife? Why God demand such a light punishment against Dave? Shouldn't they both be stoned to death?

We probably have issue whether the sex is consensual or rape. Torah seems to punish married rape victim even if the sex is not consensual if the rape happens in town and the woman doesn't scream (reference needed). So Batsheba should be stoned too.

Some think David didn't commit any sin at all
http://torahideals.com/essays-and-imaginings/david-and-bathsheba/

> When Uriah was called before David, he made reference to his general
>   as “my master, Joab” (2 Samuel 11:11). Although this form of address
>   would have been proper in the presence of his commanding officer,
>   referring to anyone other than the king as master in the presence of
>   the king himself constituted an act of rebellion punishable by death.7
>   Uriah also disobeyed David’s order to return home to his wife.8 On two
>   separate counts, therefore, Uriah placed himself in the category of
>   mored b’malchus, a rebel against the king. As such, Uriah forfeited
>   his life immediately since the extralegal powers of the monarch
>   include the authority to invoke the death penalty upon rebels without
>   the due process of law.9

We got two possibilities:

1. Either David, as king, commit a crime/sin and didn't get punished for it.
2. Or a jewish king (like pretty much any king at that time) can pretty much grab anyone's wife without even breaking the law.

Neither is good for the peasant. In any case, which one is right?

Comment: The Talmud says that David did not sin. The king is permitted to have anybody killed that he wishes, and the retroactive divorce document did go into effect. Nevertheless, what David did was not within the spirit of the law, and therefore he was punished as we see in [2 Shmuel](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b24.htm#11)

Comment: Your ending gives two choices and ignores the third which is stated in the quotes given in the question. King David took advantage of the letter of the law and was punished for it (the child died). Since they "technically" did not commit adultery, he was allowed to marry Uriah's widow. Even if they had, they would not have been stoned because there were no witnesses who could testify. However, Shlomo would not have been able to become king. The case does not show that he can grab *any* wife.

Comment: The third possibility is the second one I think.

Comment: Where do you get that a king is allowed to kill anyone he wishes?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/anyone-who-says-these-people-sinned-is-mistaken-for-real

Comment: @Jim Thio the second possibility says *any* wife which means that eh technical differences with Batsheva would not have to exist. It is more like the "right" of kings to have any woman whenever he wants no matter who she is and what her circumstances. That is like Achashveros, not King David.

Comment: Okay one more problem. You said David didn't sin because Batsheba is not technically married at that time. Yet, Batsheba is not David's wife. I thought sex outside marriage is sin. Yet David have sex with someone that's obviously not his wife and have far more problems than that. And that's okay?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31944/759

Comment: I haven't read it, but I know Rav Yaakov Medan has a sefer on David and Batsheva.

Comment: The gemara says David did not sin, but David says he did. Presumably the gemara means that it wasn't as bad as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all commentaries agree that dovid did not actually technically commit the sin of adultery. As to why this is, either Uriah was actually divorced or conditionally divorced (which took effect retroactiy when he didn't come back). 
Uriah was mored bamolchus (either because he called yoav a "master" in front of dovid or because he didn't listen to dovid to go home) and so dovid had the right to have him killed.
At the time that dovid and batsheva had relations Uriah was technically divorced. 
The question is SHOULD he have done what he did. Just for his being mored bamolchus he wouldn't have had Uriah killed it's only because he wanted his wife. While they were technically divorced, everyone understood that they weren't getting divorced because they wanted to seperated but as to not cause agunos. So when dovid and batsheva had relations was when Uriah was still alive and so dovid was in a ethical sense stealing his wife. Or according to the understanding that it was a retroactive divorce then batsheva was at that point in time still married to Uriah as only once Uriah was kille was it "revealed" that they had been divorced however long ago. 
So while dovid didn't technically sin according to the letter of the law he did commit some ethical crime.

Comment: So that's how one avoid sinning. Bang someone else's wife? Just kill the husband and keep it legal. I see why some jews are good lawyers.

Comment: @jim Thio Let's seperated court punishable crime vs sin. Dovid most definetly committed a sin, hence why he was punished and rebuked. If your question is did he do an act then the human courts can punish based upon the law, then no. There also is a discussion that dovid knew he was to have a child from her and that it ha to be in a unusual way for moshiach to come from him, but that concept is way beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that is being ignored by supposing that David did not commit the sins of adultery and murder is three-fold. First Nathan the Prophet telling David he had done wrong, the death of the baby for punishment and the fact of judgement by the sword against David’s Kingdom. 2 Samuel 12
It would seem that David was forgiven 2 Samuel 12:13

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Ben and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!